# 2 Knights against 1 pawn (endgame)

Tags: endgame, theory, knight-endgame

Why is it important to leave the opponent's pawn in this situation?

From over 7kk games only 426 ends with KNN against KP, of which 286 games (67.1%) is draw.

[image]

---

In the two knights endgame, how should we block the pawn to force checkmate? In @SmallChess's answer, GM Samuel seem have made many mistakes...

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1937249

Answer (score 6):

Endgame where two knights against a lone king is a draw, you can't force a checkmate. However, with a pawn the side with the two knights can setup a mating net without running into stalemate. That's why it's always important to leave a pawn.

Just a few days ago, Karjakin demonstrated the technique against a very strong US grandmaster. Please note in the final position, it's a stalemate without the black pawn. Please go through the game, note how Karjakin never attempted to win the final pawn.

White is threatening Nh6, Nf7#. Again, this setup is impossible without the black pawn.

> http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1937249

[image]

Comment: Yes, I mean this game. I didn't know that it was important to leave a pawn. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Maybe you have any info about this?

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto What else are you interested to know?

Comment: Emmm, about blocking a pawn. Need to block before pawn crossed the center line? In this game Samuel's  do many mistakes...

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto I'm not an endgame analysis expert. Someone else here might answer you better. Please wait a few more hours.

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto I edited your question to reflect your new question. Sorry, I'm the best person for analyzing a GM game.

Comment: The pawn needs to be blockaded behind the troitsky line to guarantee a win. There are cases where the pawn advanced up farther it is still possible to win. The game with karjakin should have been a draw though.

Comment: The Karjakin-Sevian endgame was a theoretical draw until around move 80.